# Ruby: Syntax to POST batch request with Net::HTTP to Facebook API

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api

Using curl the following command is correct, and the Facebook API replies with the expected response:

> curl -F 'access_token=TOKEN' -F 'batch=[{"method":"GET",
>   "relative_url":"facebook"},{"method":"GET",
>   "relative_url":"youtube"}]' https://graph.facebook.com

I would like to convert this to Ruby but have been struggling to find the right syntax.  I have tried variations on the below, but without luck:

> uri = URI.parse('https://graph.facebook.com')
>
> res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'access_token' => 'TOKEN', 'batch' =>
>   "[{'method':'GET', 'relative_url':'facebook'}]")

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510356/how-do-i-encode-the-symbol-for-batch-requests) and [this blog post](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578343-easy-way-to-use-graph-facebook-api-without-ad-hoc-/) here's what I got working:

```
uri = URI("https://graph.facebook.com/")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
attach = {}

attach = {'batch' => [{"method" => "GET", "relative_url"=>"facebook"}].to_json}
req.set_form_data(attach.merge('access_token' => "TOKEN"))

res = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
res.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
res.use_ssl = true

response = nil
res.start do |http|
  response = http.request(req)
end
```